# Cron expression 0 0/30 * 1/1 * ? * not working for half n hour

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I have a scheduler job for which I have configured `0 0/30 * 1/1 * ? *` as cron expression to run for every half n hour, but the scheduler is not getting triggered, instead it works fine if I set the expression for every 5 minutes like `0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *`. What might be the issue here? Is my cron expression correct?

Note: I am using [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) (in Java) and making an entry in Database scheduler table.

Comment: Have you checked invocation of your expression at *:00, *:30 time? By the way, you can check or generate your expressions [here](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Comment: instead of 0/30 can you try 0,30?

Comment: Hi mexes_S, I did make a cron expression from cronmaker. It gave me 0 '0/30 * 1/1 * ? *'. Is '*:00, *:30' cron expression? sorry i am new to cron

Comment: Hi Radu,0/0,30 should it be this way?

Comment: No he means `0 0,30 * 1/1 * ? *` instead of `0 0/30 * 1/1 * ? *`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand '1/1' for Day of month. But if you want a cron expression to run every half n hour: the cron expression correct is "0 0/30 * ? * * *"

In Java, you can test your cron expression with unit test.
org.quartz.CronExpression has a method to test next valid date.